# Where does one mine moonstone?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Trying to make the Elven armor. I found a mine that has quicksilver in Dawnstar but not sure where I can get moonstone ore outside of a shop.

Comment: You can also sometimes buy the ore (or the refined bars) directly from blacksmiths.

Comment: I can't find any moonstone ore veins out in the open. There is a lot of various ore veins on the northern coast but I haven't found any moonstone. I was looking for it myself; in fact I googled how to find moonstone ore in Skyrim and I found this site. Your best bet is probably just buy it off a blacksmith. Warmaiden's in Whiterun usually has some in stock.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[The UESP Wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Mining) lists the following locations for moonstone:

- Mzulft, southeast of Windhelm.
- Stony Creek Cave, southeast of Windhelm.
- Soljund's Sinkhole, southwest of Rorikstead.

Answer (score 0):

I found a moonstone mining area on my way up the mountain to the greybeards.

Answer (score 0):

Mzulft, the dwarven ruin to the lower east corner of the map had several

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 deposits of moonstone ore vein north west of the moonforge thing that forges the enchanted weapons, keep going up the hill and you should see some, in my ventures there is usually a bear guarding it so prepare if at low level.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the Dawnstar Loop chest. I've gotten a lot of refined moonstone out of it.